# Shortest distance in the log semiring for a weighted automaton

Tags: shortest-path, automata

I thought I'd figured this out... but I still cannot wrap my head around it.
I'm playing with OpenFst and trying to figure out how 'shortestdistance' is calculated in the 'log' semiring.
For the following little automaton,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j2Yf.png

The result of the 'shortestdistance' command is,

```
$ fstshortestdistance log.fst
0   0
1   -0.510825634
2   -2.60798359
3   -0.9162907
```

and the description for shortestdistance in log is given as,

> With the log semiring, the (log) sum of path weights to q is computed.

I feel pretty dumb but I cannot figure out what is actually happening to arrive at the final -2.6.  I've tried every variation of the logsum and ordinary sum that I can think of, even ones that seem like they shouldn't apply, but nothing yields -2.6.  It's starting to drive me crazy now.

My *intuition* in this case is that the total path probabilities for each of the two distinct strings (bc, bd) should be summed, and then the best probability should be returned.  There are two paths for (bc) and their probabilities sum to 2/3 (non-log).  The (bd) path has probability 1/3.  However, this is *definitely* not what is happening, so what *is* happening?

Answer (score 1):

The logsum of two values, 'x' and 'y' in the log semiring is defined as,

> -log( exp(-x) + exp(-y) )

and the shortest-distance in the log semiring should compute the total likelihood associated with the automaton you've defined.  The path output strings aren't relevant, but there are three distinct paths with the following associated path weights:

> x = (0,1,2):-.51083
>
> y = (0,3,2):-1.2729 = -.91629 + -.35667
>
> z = (0,3,2):-2.1202 = -.91629 + -1.204

If we sum x, y and z according to the logsum we get,

> -log( exp(-x) + exp(-y) + exp(-z) ) = -2.607

Which is what OpenFst will produce.  My guess is that you forgot the pesky negative signs.